# GitHub Repository Redirect and trying to find it through the GitHub Search API

Tags: python-3.x, api, github

I have a link for a GitHub repository and I'm using github3 with Python in order to try and search for it.

Take this link for example:

```
https://github.com/GabrielGrimberg/OOP-Assignment1-UI
```

If you go to it, you will see that it redirects to

```
https://github.com/GabrielGrimberg/RuneScape-UI
```

And thus, I can't figure out how to construct a search query that will find this specific repo.

I've tried:

```
GabrielGrimberg/OOP-Assignment1-UI in:url
GabrielGrimberg/OOP-Assignment1-UI
GabrielGrimberg/OOP-Assignment1-UI in:full_name
```

Comment: Gabriel Grimberg does not have any repo named "OOP-Assignment1-UI".  The repo is renamed thus its previous address is redirected its new address. 
https://github.com/blog/1508-repository-redirects-are-here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Github blog](https://github.com/blog/1508-repository-redirects-are-here) if a repo is renamed the old address is redirected to new address!

> We're happy to announce that starting today, we'll automatically redirect all requests for previous repository locations to their new home in these circumstances. There's nothing special you have to do. Just rename away and we'll take care of the rest.

Moreover you can check *Gabriel Grimberg* does not have any repo named "OOP-Assignment1-UI".

**Corrected answer:**

If we can first check repo details to make sure it exists/where it has moved! 
Check out the following query:

```
curl -i https://github.com/GabrielGrimberg/OOP-Assignment1-UI
```

You can get the url where it moved from the header

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2017 18:19:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: no-cache
Vary: X-PJAX
Location: https://github.com/GabrielGrimberg/RuneScape-UI
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

If the repo already existed there it would have given you the content instead of the header!
For example , try this:

```
curl -i https://github.com/GabrielGrimberg/RuneScape-UI
```

Comment: I understand that, but how would I find the new repository with a query to the GitHub API?

Comment: @Majiick no query will find "OOP-Assignment1-UI". It will always find/redirect to the new one "RuneScape-UI". Are you trying to query find whats the new repository or what? Please clarify!

Comment: I'm using the GitHub API v3 to try and query for the "OOP-Assignment1-UI" repo from user GabrielGrimberg. Obviously, it doesn't exist anymore so the query returns no results. However, I know that it redirects to the new repo. So, how do I construct a query using the old name to find the new repo?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make a request yourself and check for the redirection if the first search provided no result.

```
def get_redirection(full_name):
    try:
        json_object = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.github.com/repos/{0}'.format(full_name)).read().decode('utf-8'))
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        return None

    return json_object["full_name"]  # Will return the new full-name of the project
```